# How's python Pyminizip compress_multiple work?

Tags: python-3.x, zip

My python version is 3.5 through Anaconda on Windows 10 environment. I'm using [Pyminizip](https://github.com/smihica/pyminizip) because I need password protected for my zip files, and [Zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) doesn't support it yet.

I am able to zip single file through the function `pyminizip.compress`, and the encrypt function worked as expected. However, when trying to use `pyminizip.compress_multiple` I always encountered a Python crash (as pictures) and I believe it's due to the problem of my bad input format.

What I would like to know is: What's the acceptable format for input argument `src file LIST path`? From Pyminizip's documentation:

> pyminizip.compress_multiple(*[u'pyminizip.so', 'file2.txt'], "file.zip", "1233", 4, progress*)
>     Args:
>     1. **src file LIST path (list)**
>     2. dst file path (string)
>     3. password (string) or None (to create no-password zip)
>     4. compress_level(int) between 1 to 9, 1 (more fast)  <---> 9 (more compress)

It seems the first argument `src file LIST path` should be a list containing all files required to be zipped. Accordingly, I tried to use `compress_multiple` to compress single file with command:

> pyminizip.compress_multiple( ['Filename.txt'], 'output.zip', 'password', 4, optional)

and it lead to Python crash. So I try to add a full path into the args.

> pyminizip.compress_multiple( [os.getcwd(), 'Filename.txt'], ... )

and still, it crashed again. So I think maybe I have to split the path like this

> path = os.getcwd().split( os.sep )
>   pyminizip.compress_multiple( [path, 'Filename.txt'], ...)

still got a bad luck. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like it's not about the format of input, but potential bug... https://github.com/smihica/pyminizip/issues/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyminizip requires the path name (or relative path name from where the script is running from) in the files.

Your example:

```
pyminizip.compress_multiple( [os.getcwd(), 'Filename.txt'], ... )
```

gives a list of files of os.getcwd(), and then another file, 'Filename.txt'. You need to combine them into a single path using os.path.join()

in your filename example, you will need:

```
pyminizip.compress_multiple( [os.path.join(getcwd(), 'Filename.txt')],...)
```

conversly:

```
pyminizip.compress_multiple( [os.path.join(getcwd(), 'Filename1.txt'), os.path.join(getcwd(), 'Filename2.txt')],...)
```

Answer (score 0):

From here - [https://pypi.org/project/pyminizip/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpX4F.png), the usage of compress_multiple is

pyminizip.compress_multiple([u'pyminizip.so', 'file2.txt'], [u'/path_for_file1', u'/path_for_file2'], "file.zip", "1233", 4, progress)

The second parameter is a bit confusing, but if used, it will create a zip file, which when uncompressed, will create a directory structure like:

[image]